# CSS - background image display looks different on mobiles than when browser resized

Tags: css, mobile

I am using the Wordpress Zerif Lite template and am having issues with the background image display on mobiles.  I spent time perfecting the position of the image so its looks good when the browser was resized to mobile size but when tested on a mobile it looks totally different.  Why does it look different on a mobile?  Can anyone help?

```
.header-content-wrap {
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: right top !important;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.08);
    padding: 285px 0 210px;
}
```

Please see the screen shots below:

mobiles:

**link removed as now resolved.

Resized web browser:

**link removed as now resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [background-position:](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/background-position/). Looks like it's using `right top` but maybe you just want `center`. If it is different then you might be using [media queries](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/media/) which is why they could have different positions based on screen width.

**UPDATE**

The image is applied to the body as a background. On the iPhone6 the background ends up being 375px x 11267px. It looks funny because you're zooming based on an exaggerated vertical using background:cover. If you want to fix the problem you'll need to hide that background image when your screen ratio gets crazy like that. I understand you're doing that because you want a fixed position but attaching to the body isn't helping. You could make a fixed position div that is 100% the viewport width and height for the same effect in the background.

Comment: please, css questions are off-topic, don't encourage people to keep asking them here.

Comment: stack overflow is almost always the sink for all non wordpress specific questions asked here

Comment: it seems like that to you only because you are an "advanced user" of it. There are many low level questions over there. What people consider it is irrelevant for this site, the important is what the actual community here thinks, if you want to discuss it you are more then welcome to do it on meta which exists exactly for this kind of discussions.

Comment: Oops sorry, seems the stackoverflow / exchange police are out!!  I originally posted in stackoverflow and someone told me to post it here!!  Can't win :(

Comment: anyway, with regards to your answer, its not the position thats the issue unless its set different somewhere else.  Its as though Wordpress is adding some different styling for mobiles which I cannot seem to track.  The positioning works perfect when resizing the browser so that leads me to assume the media queries work fine.